# Which element in Flash Builder defines the iPhone app shortcut name?

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I've created an air app in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 with air 3.5 for publishing on Android and iOS. My application.xml file starts off like this:

```
<id>com.one.two.three</id>
<filename>foobar</filename>
<name>FOO BAR</name>
<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
```

When I exported the release build, and installed the App on an android device, the icon appeared in the applications folder with the name "`FOO BAR`".

However, when I installed the app on an iPhone, the icon appeared on the homescreen with the name "`foobar`".

The desired name for both devices is `FOO BAR`. What element is setting this incorrectly for iOS? I imagine it's the `<filename>` value, but I would really rather not have spaces in my filename.

Looking forward to an answer, I've checked other resources like:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html, but it doesn't get very descriptive with what element does what.

Thank you very much for your time,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this with a grain of salt, but like it says in your xml :

```
<!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
<name></name>
```

Like it says there, This value is only for your AIR installer.  The node you are looking for is the `<filename>` node.

```
<!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
```

Considering iOS will install directly from the store, you will never have the need to specify a name for the installer when it comes to iOS.  I think the `<name>` node is for desktop apps or .apks where you actually see the installer.

How about naming them both FOOBAR? :)

Comment: Thanks Marco! That makes sense to me. Didn't realize it was only for the AIR installer. I'll make the changes accordingly.

FOOBAR it is!